# Output string using php printf

Tags: content

I'm trying to display a texts with functions on my page. Please find the code below. I'm not getting the output I want.

```
<?php $content = the_content(); ?>
<?php printf(__('Output : %1$s', 'theme'), $content); ?>
```

Which Outputs :

```
Foo
Output  :
```

I need my output to be like this :

```
Output  : Foo
```

---

Answer from Kim Christensen :

```
<?php $content = get_the_content(); ?>
<?php printf(__('Output : %1$s', 'theme'), $content); ?>
```

Works perfectly :

```
Output : Foo
```

---

Answer from Pieter Goosen :

```
<?php $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() ); ?>
<?php printf(__('Output : %1$s', 'theme'), $content); ?>
```

It pushes my content below :

```
Output :
Foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_content()` prints it output to screen. What you want is to return that output and assign a variable to it.

You should note, although `get_the_content()` do exactly what you want, it only returns unfiltered content, and not filtered content like `the_content()`. You should manually add those filters, which is real easy.

You can do the following

```
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
```

### EDIT

It seems the above approach pushes the content part to the next line when the filters are applied to `get_the_content()`.

A work around here would be to concatenate `Output :` to `get_the_content()` and then applying the content filters to that

```
<?php $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', 'Output :' . get_the_content() ); ?>
<?php printf(__( '%1$s', 'theme'), $content); ?>
```

would give you what you need

Comment: Hi Pieter, I've tried your code. However, it pushes my content below. Please check my edits above. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you have a line break right at the top of your content

Comment: Looking at your last update, it seems that when the filters is applied on `get_the_content()`, the issue starts which can be because of the added p tags or a line break

Comment: Thanks Pieter, I thought it follows the printf? Is there a way to ignore the line break?

Comment: Please see my update, it should work now

Comment: Thanks, got it to work perfectly. Do you have a doc link that writes about difference between unfiltered and filtered content?

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked. I don't know of any documentation on that subject, at least, I haven't looked for such documentation. In this context, `get_the_content()` is unfiltered and that is quite obvious if you look at the content. Also, no harmful injected code, if any, has been removed, so `get_the_content()` can be harmful. `the_content()` on the otherhand has been filtered as you can see and any harmfull injected code is removed. You need to dig into the source code for these two functions to fully understand how they work :-)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `get_the_content()`, 
`the_content()` prints the content.

`get_the_content()` will be assigned to your variable.

Answer (score 1):

Kim is correct.

`get_the_content()` displays your intended result.

```
<?php $content = get_the_content(); 
printf("Output: %1$s", $content); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another approach:

```
ob_start();
the_content();
$content = ob_get_clean();
```